# Why is `a (b.c do;end)` not a syntactically correct Ruby program?

Tags: ruby, syntax

Why gives this code in ruby18 and ruby19 a syntax error:

```
a (b.c do;end)
```

I would have expected it to mean the following. A call to the method `a` with one argument. The parentheses after the space are not method argument parentheses, but only normal parentheses like you can put almost everywhere. The argument is the return value of the call to the method `c` on the object `b` with a block.

All of the following are however interpreted as syntactically correct by ruby18. Only the first of these examples is treated as syntactically incorrect by ruby19.

```
a (b do;end)
```

and:

```
a (b.c {})
```

and:

```
(b.c do;end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space in between the method name and the `(`. Ruby used to warn that this was dodgy and it does seem to throw ruby 1.9 off in some cases.

Comment: I know, these parenthesis after the space are not normal method parenthesis. My intuition says, it still should be syntacticly valid. Why is it not?

Comment: Apparently, it's because of matz's brain: http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/84104?help-en

Comment: @Frederick Cheung: The reason why the space is generating a warning is because the syntax is *ambiguous* at that point. It could be parenthesis for a method call or for the first argument, both would be possible and Matz couldn't find a resolution for this conflict. It still doesn't explain why `a (b.c do;end)` is a *syntax error*.

Comment: @DarkDust because syntax is defined by rules, and the rules (in yacc given by Matz) say it's a syntax error. Some things, as my physics professor used to say, just are :)

Comment: @lain this question is not about laws of nature, but about a property of a man engineered software